# Binding collection of collection to datagrid source in WPF MVVM Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view model in the following structure:

```
Viewmodel:
public System SystemLst
{
get;set;
}
```

Model:

```
public class System
{
    public ObservableCollection<Properties> PropertySource
        {
            get { return _dutPropertiesColl; }
            set { 
                _dutPropertiesColl = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DUTPropertySource");
            }
        }


        public ObservableCollection<SubSystem> SubSystemList
        {
            get { return _subSystemList; }
            set
            {
                _subSystemList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SubsystemList");
            }
        }
}

public SubSystem SubSystemList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> TestLists
        {
          get;
      set;
        }
}
```

I have a WPF form with datacontext set as the view model. And there is a datagrid in the form whose itemsource should be set to TestLists.
I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgList" ItemsSource="{Binding Systemlst.SubSystemList.TestLists}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean, each row in your data grid should represent an ObservableCollection<Test>, with the cells of this row filled with the Test objects from that ObservableCollection<Test> collection? Please clarify by editing and improving your question.

Comment: what is test here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should be a simple class of access type as public. The view model should have the ObservableCollection SubSystemList which will act as the ItemSource.